# Multiple tray icons when using TrayItem in Windows 10

Tags: swt, windows-10

I have a standalone Java based SWT in the front end application. I contribute a custom icon to the system tray menu using SWT tray

```
trayItem.setImage(image);
```

Now whenever my application is closed, I dispose of the tray item.
But when my system goes to sleep and comes back again, the application is very much running. When the system comes back again, my application tries to update the tray item's image.

While updating the image I see multiple tray icons appear in the system tray. So  the number of icons keep on increasing as many times as my applications wakes up.

Unfortunately this is only reproducible on Windows 10 but not on earlier versions. Has anyone experienced this problem? I don't have any windows 10 system with me. Otherwise I could have written a sample code to reproduce it.

Comment: Does the tray item go away if you move your mouse over it?

I've noticed some apps I use on Windows 7 (Thunderbird, etc) that contribute tray items sometimes leave the displayed until I hover the mouse over it ... at which point the icon disappears.

Comment: Nope these tray icons are not going away.....

Comment: I was jut playing with this ... are you closing the TrayItem you are attaching menu items to?

Comment: Yes so i dispose the tray item when the application is closed, but in the sleep i can not do it since application is technically not closed in sleep

Comment: I believe you are facing this issue? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488739. What version of SWT are you using?

Comment: Yes...that is the same issue...its fixed with the recet versio of SWT

Comment: @TarunLalwani We have 4.3, please just put there an answer with this (ideally in which version it was fixed) and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Polostor. Done posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

Fix for this issue is available from Eclipse 4.7 (Oxygen).

Answer (score 1):

You are facing bug defined on below link

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488739.

You need SWT 4.7+, the issue has been fixed in the same

Comment: Btw isn't it from 4.6? - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_activity.cgi?id=488739